# best way to get large data from database with pagination in php?

Tags: php, select, pagination

I have a large amount of data in PHP. like I'm developing properties web app. In the database, we have thousands of rows in the database. I'm using

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM properties limit $page_first_result, $results_per_page";
```

limit query with pagination. Is this the best way to handle a large amount of data? or there is another way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice and best ways in pagination is using the `limit` and `offset` and also optimizing the output.

Also [Pear::Pager](https://pear.php.net/package/Pager) can help with the output, and to limit the database traffic to only what you need, you can use a wrapper provided in the examples that come with it.

you may take a look at [this article](https://www.xarg.org/2011/10/optimized-pagination-using-mysql/) too. it's providing data about Optimized Pagination using MySQL, making the difference between counting the total amount of rows, and pagination.